# Civic Bad Mileage

Tags: civic, fuel-consumption, mileage

I have honda civic 98 with D16Y4 engine and auto transmission.I'm getting low mileage 9-10km/L without a.c, driving with light foot with  rpm between 2k-3k. I avoid long idling, drive within city usually heavy traffic using engine oil 10w-40 Liquimoly. Cleaned O2 sensor with this method[check here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwieopK8nN_gAhWGjqQKHR2ECDEQzPwBegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FClean-an-Oxygen-Sensor&psig=AOvVaw13fHecMlQ_ZvR3PBd11Y2S&ust=1551470589383530), changed fuel filter, air filter but haven't gone above 10km/L. Tried 93RoN but it makes no difference used 87RoN normally. I keep tyres pressure at 30. How come I get better mileage ?
There's no issues with car other than mileage issue. Suggestions are welcome

Comment: How many miles are on your Civic? When was the last time you had the O2 sensors replaced? Cleaning them will pretty much only destroy them, at least I wouldn't trust them to run correctly after the attempt.

Comment: Engine was swapped 2 years back when I bought this car it's mileage was 5km/l because O2 sensor was missing then I put a used O2 sensor because here it's hard to find a new one after that mileage improved to 9-10km/L but I found better mileage of this engine on internet around 14-16km/L. I'm not sure about engine mileage but since I bought this car I ran it for approximately 30,000Km till now.

Answer (score 1):

That actually doesn't sound that bad - it's actually pretty much what the book figures suggest for that car/engine combo during urban driving.

So I suspect you may be chasing a non-existent problem.